# Probability over time period

Tags: statistics, probability

Can someone help me with this probability question.  Lets say I know the following:

- Probability of event from time period 1 to period 2 (x)
- Probability of event from time period 1 to period 3 (y)

What would be the probability of time period 2 to period 3?

Thanks in advance?
John

Comment: Paste this question at http://math.stackexchange.com/ and then let me know, I will answer it. :)

Comment: Sorry, just added the question to math stack exchange:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468942/probability-over-time-period

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

T is the time of the event.

Probability of event from time period 1 to period 2 (x): P(t<sub>1</sub> <= T < t<sub>2</sub>) = x

Probability of event from time period 1 to period 3 (y): P(t<sub>1</sub> <= T < t<sub>3</sub>) = y

What would be the probability of time period 2 to period 3?

P(t<sub>2</sub> <= T < t<sub>3</sub>) = P(t<sub>1</sub> <= T < t<sub>3</sub>) - P(t<sub>1</sub> <= T < t<sub>2</sub>) = y - x